# How do AeroVironment's Switchblades steer their flight?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, engineering

I've recently been to a defense expo and saw a previewed Switchblade 300 at the AeroVironment booth. It got me questioning how the Swtichblade, and similar fold-out drones steer their flight. The Switchblade lacks ailerons, elevators, or rudders. So how do they steer? This question has been asked before, but I feel the answers were lacking. Here are pictures I took of the Switchblade 300.

Thank You

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah looking at this, I realize that they no longer have ailerons/elevons... I will have to update my answer over at the other thread. I hope I can use your photos for updating my answer. My best guess is that they now tilt the entire wing for roll and pitch control.

Comment: After some looking around, I am convinced that this is a presentation model, which does not feature the ailerons which are normally used for flight controls. See this video of the Block 20 model with ailerons displayed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pTMM9ZUpTQ.